# Adding a disclaimer to a website made using image slices

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to create a disclaimer for a website that was built using image slices (please feel free to correct me if my terminology is in error). The domain is at http://elitemedicalsupplyofny.com . Every attempt that I've made at adding a line of text at the bottom of the page ends in an undesired result. Either the images get pushed out of their place or the text shows up at the bottom of the page and scrolling is required to view the disclaimer (not ideal but, so far, appears to be the best solution given my knowledge of html).

I'm wondering if anyone has any type of solution of adding a disclaimer to the bottom of the site, positioned a line below the current contact information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are adding the copyright information into a set sized table, rather than adding to the table you should add it via DIV styling which is more flexible in styling.

**Add Disclaimer Below Table**

```
<table> Your Table Contents Here </table>

<div>
    <p style="text-align:center;>I am the Disclaimer</p>
</div>
```

**Fixed Disclaimer at Bottom of Page**

```
<table> Your Table Contents Here </table> 

<div style="position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;width:100%;">
    <p style="text-align:center;>I am the Disclaimer</p>
</div>
```

## Fixed Position Disclaimer or Footer with CSS

Rather than using inline styling you should use css to your advantage, like so:

**HTML**

```
<table> Your table contents here </table>

<div class="disclaimer">
    <p>I am the Disclaimer</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.disclaimer {
            position:fixed;
            width:100%;
            left:0;
            bottom:0;
            }
.disclaimer p {
              text-align:center;
              }
```